# Return smallest two numbers with negatives in Excel

Tags: excel, numbers, return, traversal

If I have an array of numbers in Excel like below:

```
-5    1    4    -2
```

I need to return -5 and -2 (each in a separate cell).

The =SMALL(array, 1) does not work because the numbers in my array are less than 1. Is there a workaround so I can traverse trough the array and return the two smallest numbers?

Comment: `=SMALL({-5,1,4,-2},ROW(1:1))` filled down another row doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but `=SMALL()` works just fine for me for your use case as I understand it. Negative values are acceptable inputs to that function.

Comment: `=SMALL(A1:D1,1)` and `=SMALL(A1:D1,2)` works perfect for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your numbers are in the range A2:A5 and

If you want the formula to return the output in rows, place this formula in any cell and copy it down.

```
=SMALL($A$2:$A$5,ROWS(A$1:A1))
```

If you want the formula to return the output across the columns, place this formula in any cell and copy it across or right.

```
=SMALL($A$2:$A$5,COLUMNS($A1:A1))
```

Change the ranges as required.

Comment: This is what I tried but for some reason, it returning a #NUM error

Comment: I feel pretty embarrassed now, but the data I was working with was boring stored as text, thus was not being picked up as a number. Case solved, really appreciated everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

To get the smallest `=MIN(-5,1,4,-2)`, to get the second smallest `=SMALL({-5,1,4,-2},2)`